# Remove .html from website including in subdirectories

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've tried a lot of the answers here unfortunately I didn't find an answer which worked for me.

I have a website which is in the format of [www.website.com/page.html](http://www.website.com/page.html) and my goal is to display [www.website.com/page](http://www.website.com/page) whether the user enters [www.website.com/page](http://www.website.com/page) or [www.website.com/page.html](http://www.website.com/page.html) (SEO reasons as well). So I have the following snippet which works

```
#1) redirect file.html to file
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+).html [NC]
RewriteRule .+ /%1 [L,R=301]
#2) rewrite /file to file.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule (.*)/?$ /$1.html [L]
```

However I have other URLs which are the format of [www.website.com/blog/text.html](http://www.website.com/blog/text.html) and the above doesn't work for them. I've tried modifying the above but with no success. My goal is the URL to be [www.website.com/blog/text](http://www.website.com/blog/text).

Any help will be deeply appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have your .htaccess rules in following manner. This should be able to handle both the cases IMHO. I have changed the rules and regex in your existing rules. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON

#1) redirect file.html to file
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/([^.]+)\.html\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [L,R=301]

#2) rewrite /file to file.html
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ /$1.html [L]
```

Comment: Unfortunately the .html is still there for the /blog/ pages.

Comment: @devinthemaking, could you please do check my edited rules once and let me know how it goes.

Comment: Cleared up my cache several times, tried with different browsers, still the same. I can give you an URL of the website if that would help.

Comment: @devinthemaking, sure you could mention like: `http://localhost:80/test/test2` etc manner

Comment: @devinthemaking, In my humble opinion you need not to mention actual site, localhost like example in my previous comment will work. Do you have any other rules apart from these in your .htaccess file?

Comment: I do, thats the whole content of it RewriteEngine on
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^http://localhost.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.localhost.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NC,L,QSA]
#Force index to be root
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index\.html$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
#1) redirect file.html to file
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/([^.]+)\.html\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [L,R=301]
#2) rewrite /file to file.html
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ /$1.html [L]

Comment: @devinthemaking, could you please these rules(my answer ones) at the top of your htaccess once and try again please.

Comment: Still the same result.

Comment: @devinthemaking, could you please post a dummy/test line like `-------` in your htaccess file and hit any link and see if you get 500 internal Error. This test tells us if our htaccess file is enabled or not. kindly do try this and let me know how it goes.

Comment: It's enabled, I've already broken the website a couple of times.

Comment: @devinthemaking, ok could you please try keeping only posted rules once and see how it goes? Meanwhile I am checking your full htaccess which you posted, cheers.

Comment: My htaccess now is only your above comment and the html is still present in the /blog/ pages URL.

Comment: @devinthemaking, ok is there any other htaccess apart from this in your system? Because if yes then that may also impact these rules/

Comment: No there isn't another htaccess file.

Comment: @devinthemaking, ok what is the exact location of your htaccess file? Eg: `/root/singh/test/.htaccess` and what is the location of html files also? Let met see if its related to that.

Comment: My structure is root->.htaccess. Inside the root I have the main pages like contact.html. In the root I also have blog folder which contains the pages of which I can't remove the .html from the URL.

Comment: @devinthemaking, ohhh is it like `/root/.htaccess` and `/root/blog/test.html`?

Comment: Yes, exactly...

Comment: @devinthemaking, but I am still wondering why redirection is not happening. Because first set of rules are totally fine as far as I see them.

Comment: Apparently somebody created another htaccess in the blog directory which is breaking your code above.. I'm going to further investigate this on. Thank you so much for your help! Going to mark it as resolved as the issue is in the other htaccess.

Comment: @devinthemaking, your welcome, cheers and happy issue is resolved cheers 